# New-ADGroup - Using -join and Variable in a PS cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been delving into PS scripting over the last few months and I was attempting to script out AD group creations. Right now, I'm asking the following:

```
$GroupNameRO = Read-Host -Prompt 'What Read Only AD group name do you want to use'
$GroupNameRW = Read-Host -Prompt 'What Read Write AD group name do you want to use'
$RequestNum = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the request number for this share'
```

Then putting it all together here:

```
New-ADGroup -name $GRPnameRW -path 'OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=test,DC=local' -groupscope 'global' -Description -join('Request #',$RequestNum)
```

and finally receiving this error:

```
New-ADGroup : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ADGroup -name $GRPnameRW -path 'OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=test,DC=local' -g ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup
```

Has anyone used the -join within a parameter / am I formatting everything correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value for the -Description parameter is incorrect. This should get you the result you're looking for:

```
New-ADGroup -name $GRPnameRW -path 'OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=test,DC=local' -groupscope 'global' -Description "Request #$RequestNum"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
... -Description (('Request #',$RequestNum) -join 'something')
```

You need to do it like this. Think of it this way:

```
-Description (expression)
```

because `Description` has to be a result of an expression we need to enclose the expression in `()`, everything inside `()` gets executed first.

And for `-join` to work we need to feed values into it, so:

```
(values) -join 'what_are_we_joining_with'
```

ps. you don't really need `()` around values you are passing to join in some cases: `'a','b' -join ""` works. But I thinks its nicer this way and more intuitive with `()`.